# "num_rows" issue for views in Big Query Python library

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I need to obtain the total number of rows for a view on Big Query, using the python library "bigquery" and without a query.

According to this [documentation website](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.html?highlight=num_rows#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.num_rows), in theory, all I need is to get the view reference and then get the number of rows with "num_rows".

Unfortunatly, in practice, this does not work for me.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

view_id = "my-project.my_dataset.my_view"
view = client.get_table(view_id)
n_rows = view.num_rows
```

The code above returns 0 for all the BQ views I am working on, even though in reality they are not empty

Comment: does other properties, like `view.table_id`, work ok?

Comment: all the ones I tried worked yes

Answer (score 0):

Views return num_rows=0 or total_rows=0.
Only tables return non-zero value.
[Four Efficient Techniques to Retrieve Row Counts in BigQuery Tables and Views](https://www.metaplane.dev/blog/four-efficient-techniques-to-retrieve-row-counts-in-bigquery-tables-and-views)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).